# Image resolution vs screen resolution vs camera resolution

Tags: java, android, image

I am making an android based app that includes image capturing and displaying it on the screen.

I’m currently using Android Studio to develop this application.

I am developing this app with a Xiaomi RedMi note5A/5. The screen resolution is 1280x720. However, its camera can take a much higher resolution image. Will the phone’s screen resolution be able to display that captured imaged at its best resolution or will it be scaled down to fit 1280x720 due to screen limitations.

I’ve tried looking up the method for `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` method in the library and attempted to use it. The supported preview sizes are only up to 1280x720. Please advise! Thanks

Comment: you obviously can't show more pixels than your screen physically has. But you can take larger photo if your camera supports it. When you showing it on the screen, it will be downscaled to fit yor physical resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the picture has more pixels than the screen, then the image must be scaled or cropped in order to be displayed. An easy way to deal with this is to simply set your picture as the source of an [*ImageView*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView). Android will handle the scaling, so your image can fit the *view*. See below for a simple example.

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(pictureBmp);
```

Comment: in that sense, i would assume that the camera supports such high resolution to be exported into a computer for viewing? otherwise why would a camera be so powerful, such that the screen display cannot even support it. 

the scaling will affect the resolution of the image to be of a lower resolution?

Am i right to say if i would like to display a high resolution image on my phone, the only option is to go for higher end phones such as the Samsung Galaxy S9?

Comment: once again, thanks @Talender for your help :) appreciate it

Comment: Yes, the only reason I can think of is that the picture taken is meant to be displayed not only by the phone, but also by other devices or even printed. I've found [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-the-iPhone-8-have-a-better-camera-resolution-than-the-iPhone-8-screen) question on Google that might help you better understand this concept.